# Public Key Crypto with Private Key Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, key, public

I'm trying to implement the following in C#:

I want a Generator that internally houses a public-key encryption routine.  It can take a byte array that's provided to it (usually by a Client described below) and encrypt it with its private key.

A Client has a public key that it shares with the Generator.  It takes the result from the Generator and decrypts it using the public key.  It takes the byte array that it initially provided to the Generator and compares the result to see if they line up.  The idea is that if they match, it's able to verify with some degree of certainty that whoever generated the encrypted bytes possessed the private key.  It's also able to verify that the specific encrypted value corresponds to the data it provided.

Most of the built-in C# public-key crypto libraries I'm seeing want to associate the private key with decryption (such as RSACryptoServiceProvider).  I can see why, since a lot of scenarios involve protecting the decryption side of the process instead of the encryption.  Are there any C# libraries that make protecting the encryption process straight forward?  I've tried looking at Bouncy Castle all morning, but I'm having a difficult time getting it to work for even basic scenarios.  The documentation leaves something to be desired...

Again, my main goal is to make sure that whatever produced the encryption possesses the private key.  It's also necessary that the Client can make sure the Generator's result corresponds to its provided info.  If there are alternative approaches that I'm missing that might conform better to available libraries, I'm all ears :)

Comment: so you want the Generator to produce a signature?

Comment: This has "chosen plaintext attack" written all over it. Public key cryptosystems rely on the possessor of the private key being the entity that generates the message to be signed with that key. If you want the generator to be able to prove that it possesses a private key associated with a given public key then have the generator generate a document consisting of random bits that it can hash, and then publish the hash, the signed-with-private-key hash, and the document. Anyone with the public key can then verify that the hash, signed hash, and document match.

Comment: If you absolutely must have the client -- who remember *should be assumed by the generator to be an attacker* -- provide the document then at least have the generator *append random bits to the document*, then *hash the new document*, and then *encrypt the hash*. Again, the generator can publish the modified document, the hash and the signed hash and the client can verify that they all match each other. But only do that if absolutely necessary. You never want to encrypt a document *on behalf of an attacker*.

Comment: @iddqd Is there a reason you don't want to use normal [digital signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)? For example the ones offered by `RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData`. RSA signatures internally use the RSA private key operation, but they add appropriate hashing and padding, which are important for security. You can only sign if you know the private key, and you can verify with the public key.

Comment: @Eric A chosen plaintext attack doesn't seem applicable here.  The plaintext itself isn't something I'm actually trying to protect, so it's not really a big deal if someone guesses the plaintext that the Client produced.  

The concern is that the Client knows the encrypted result came from the Generator, *and* that the encrypted result is derived from the response originally submitted by the Client.  I'm not trying to secure a means for the Generator and Client to share secret data over the cipher.

Comment: The signature method works great for the Client knowing the Generator produced the response/signature, but I don't think it helps out with the Client being able to take the encrypted response and checking that it corresponds with the data it originally submitted.

Comment: A point of clarification that doesn't really impact the implementation but may help with understanding what I'm trying to do is that the data submitted from the Client to the Generator is a hashed ID for that Client.  So the Generator is really returning an encrypted reply that is theoretically only valid for that specific Client.  The Client needs to take the encrypted reply and somehow match it up with its own ID to make sure it was actually intended for it and not a different Client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write:

> Again, my main goal is to make sure that whatever produced the
>   encryption possesses the private key.

As mentioned by CodesInChaos you could properly use a signature to achieve this. Usually a signature is used to verify that some data are produced by somebody holding a certain private key, but here you can use it to verify the key holder himself. If you ask him to sign something you produced, you can check that he is in possession of the private key that corresponds to your public key by use of a signature check.

Signatures actually works by making a one-way-hash of some data, and then encrypting this hash using a private key. A public key can then be used to verify the signature, by decrypting the hash and compare it with a recalculated hash value of the data. Only a person possessing the private key, can make the encrypted version of the hash. Sort of what you intend to do in the first place.